# Full Calendar width in Wix

Tags: fullcalendar

[View Wix Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fssR9.png)

Hi guys,

Total newb here. We have added full calendar in a 'custom element' in Wix. But as you can see it is expanding out of the html box it has been put in and I can't work out how to reduce the width to it doesn't do this. I have no power over Wix HTML or custom element, so it would need to be fixed in js, or css. I'm only a beginner so any help would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing may help you, if you are able to change the calendar options via this widget

Comment: Thanks for that. I have checked this out but can't see how to apply in the js or html file though?

Comment: Well I don't know precisely what your JS or HTML file look like, so it's hard to advise. If you can paste some code, it will be easier to help